# JavaFX Image class

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

So i was trying to display an image in javaFX using the class Image as is shown in the following link

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/javafx-2-how-to-load-image.html

But Image class is abstract and cannot be initiated. How can i display the image??

Comment: `javafx.scene.image.Image` is not abstract. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html  Make sure you are importing the correct `Image` class. Also, your image needs to go into an `ImageView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you are importing [`javafx.scene.image.Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) rather than `java.awt.Image`